# Lexik JWT authentication problem "Invalid credentials"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am new to symfony and I am using LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle for authorization.
I am using symfony 6.0.2 and 2.14 lexic version. I am using Postgresql 12.9.
My security.yaml:

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false


            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

My fos_rest.yaml:

```
# Read the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html
fos_rest: 
  body_listener:
      enabled: true
#    param_fetcher_listener:  true
#    allowed_methods_listener:  true
#    routing_loader: true
#    view:
#        view_response_listener:  true
#    exception:
#        codes:
#            App\Exception\MyException: 403
#        messages:
#            App\Exception\MyException: Forbidden area.
  format_listener:
       rules:
           - { path: ^/api, prefer_extension: true, fallback_format: json, priorities: [ json ] }
```

My lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml :

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: 3600
```

**My database was configured correctly and it is working and my passphrase is also correct**
My user entity is this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
   /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }
}
```

I am sending this request:

```
{
    "username": "azamjon",
    "password":"1234"
}
```

**Database have these informations**
What I am making wrong? The response is :

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid credentials."
}
```

routes.yaml:

```
# controllers:
#     resource: ../src/Controller/
#     type: annotation

# kernel:
#     resource: ../src/Kernel.php
#     type: annotation

products:
    path: /api/product 
    controller: App\Controller\ProductController::indexAction
    methods : [GET]

products_store:
    path: /api/product_store
    controller: App\Controller\ProductController::createAction
    methods : [POST]

products_show:
    path: /api/product_show/{id}
    controller: App\Controller\ProductController::showAction
    methods : [GET]

products_delete:
    path: /api/product_delete/{id}
    controller: App\Controller\ProductController::deleteAction
    methods : [DELETE]

products_update:
    path: /api/product_update/{id}
    controller: App\Controller\ProductController::products_update
    methods : [PATCH]    

# register:
#   path: /api/register
#   controller: App\Controller\AuthController::register
#   methods: POST

api_login_check:
  path: /api/login_check
```

Comment: You should check logs (`var/logs/dev.log`) to have more details. You'll get some stack trace showing up where the authenticator is failing. Then, open the source code and dig into the details from here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the option `user_identity_field: email` since default is set to `username` in `lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml`

```
#config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: 3600
    user_identity_field: email
```

Also you can add `username_path` to your `security.yaml` for less confusion:

```
#config/packages/security.yaml
json_login:
    check_path: /api/login_check
    success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
    failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
    username_path: email
    password_path: password
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it was because the password was not hashed in my database... care about this and config :

```yaml
# security.yaml

login:
    pattern: ^/api/login
    stateless: true
    json_login:
        check_path: /api/login_check
        username_path: email
        success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
        failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```

```yaml
# lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml

lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: 3600
    user_identity_field: email
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the password hashing done while registering the user is done using the password-hasher bundle

```
composer require symfony/password-hasher
```

therefore, make sure to follow the documentation :
[Password-hasher in symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/passwords.html#configuring-a-password-hasher)

and, implement the password hasher to register the user.

Answer (score -1):

You try to login with username but, symfony wait e-mail

```
providers:
  # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
  app_user_provider:
    entity:
      class: App\Entity\User
      property: email
```

Try to replace `property: email` to `property: username`